# How do I match a string with an array element?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following:

```
titles = []
url = []

titles.each do |link|
  if link[:href] =~ 'http://www.google.com'
    url.push(link[:href])
  end
end
```

But I keep getting a TypeError:

```
TypeError: type mismatch: String given
```

P.S. I am trying to use Nokogiri to parse the links returned from a particular URL. If anyone has any links, aside from the Nokogiri tutorial/wiki, about how to best do that, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you have a variable 'titles' that actually contains 'link' entities?

Comment: What difference does that make? It's related to what I am trying to do with the script. It's a business logic decision.

Comment: I was trying to see how I could help with the quandary in your postscript. In general, extracting links from a document is `doc.find('//a[href]')` but can't help further without knowing more about these href-containing titles.

Comment: Sorry....what I am trying to do, is basically parse a page with a ton of links...and depending on the name/title of those links, do something with them. So, for instance, if I get 5 links, and I am looking for the string 'Google', I want to parse those 5 links, look to see if the anchor text, i.e. `<a href="google.com">Google</a>`, contains the word 'Google' or 'google', then I push the `href` into an array or some other data structure that I can then process later. Does that make sense? So, `title` is basically the anchor text, whereas `link` is the `href` value.

Comment: @MarkThomas I am not sure how to notify you of an updated comment, I hope SO does, because am interested in hearing what you have to say.

Comment: Yes, I get notified. I have added an answer which I think addresses your underlying need, not just your stated need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=~` operator is used for matching Regexp, not strings.

> Match—If obj is a Regexp, use it as a pattern to match against str,and
>   returns the position the match starts, or nil if there is no match.
>   Otherwise, invokes obj.=~, passing str as an argument. The default =~
>   in Object returns nil.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E

This would work, assuming you want to check if `http://www.google.com` is included in the string :

```
titles = []
url = []

titles.each do |link|
    if link[:href] =~ /http:\/\/www.google.com/
       url.push(link[:href])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to use Nokogiri to parse the links returned from a particular URL.

Though Nokogiri makes it easy, there are even easier ways. Ruby's built-in URI has the [URI.extract](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract) method. From the docs:

> Extracts URIs from a string. If block given, iterates through all matched URIs. Returns nil if block given or array with matches.
>   Usage

```
require "uri"

URI.extract("text here http://foo.example.org/bla and here mailto:test@example.com and here also.")
# => ["http://foo.example.com/bla", "mailto:test@example.com"]
```

You can tell it what schemes to use, so it will only retrieve HTTP or HTTPS or whatever you are looking for.

Comment: I like this suggestion, except that I don't want JUST the URIs in a given link. I want the text associated with the link - the anchor tag also. Based on the docs for URI.extract, it seems that it only manages the URL, and not any elements around it...if that makes sense.

Comment: It only returns the values in the page that match a URL regular expression. It doesn't do any tag parsing like Nokogiri does. So, it's functional for retrieving URIs but is not good for the surrounding tags or content. According to your question, that was all you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing from follow-up comments that you really want to search the text portion of all the links, that's definitely something that can be done with Nokogiri. In fact, it can be done with a single XPath expression!

```
urls = doc.xpath("//a[contains(text(), '#{search_term}')]/@href")
```

where `search_term` contains the string you are looking for.

This can be modified to make it case-insensitive. Unfortunately, Nokogiri uses XPath 1.0 so the convenient XPath 2.0 function `lower-case()` is not available. There is a workaround: the use of `translate()`.

```
upper = ("A".."Z").to_a.join
lower = ("a".."z").to_a.join
urls = doc.xpath("//a[contains(translate(.,'#{upper}','#{lower}'), '#{search_term.downcase}')]/@href")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have a link that I can learn more about xpath? I looked through Nokogiri's docs - namely here: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html  - and I found a section that refers to a `chapter` on xpath, but I can't find that chapter. It said this: `You can use any XPath or CSS query you like (see the chapter on XPath and CSS syntax for more information)`. Where can I get more information?

Comment: Btw, what does `@href` contain? Where is that initialized or does it not matter?

Comment: There are many XPath tutorials on the web. I highly recommend learning XPath; they are like regular expressions for XML/HTML. To answer your other question, `@href` refers to an "href" attribute node, which is considered a child node of the element (in this case `a`). The `[]` brackets are called a predicate, it helps me to think of them as a "such that" condition modifying the element.

Comment: This is definitely nice and succinct. The issue I have is that it seems to return only one link. How do I let it return ALL the links that contain that search term? I was thinking I would put this in a loop, but not quite sure how to do that..given that the `doc.xpath` expression seems to be parsing the entire page and evaluating the links in one go. So not sure how to split up the operations into a loop. Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting...ok, will look into XPath tutorials for sure. But any ideas on the other question about the loop?

Comment: It returns *all* the links. `urls` is an array of all matches.

Comment: Ok...one more thing, how do I modify it to search for multiple strings? I tried `urls = site.xpath("//a[contains(text(), '#{search_term || term2 || term3}')]/@href")` but that seems to not do any of the other conditionals, if it finds any links with `search_term`. I also tried `&&` between the terms, but that didn't return any results - because it was searching for everything in one link. I know I can simply run 3 versions of this command with each of the variables, but that doesn't seem very DRY to me. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`=~` is used to find if there is regular expression match against a string. If there is a match it **returns the index of the match**, otherwise returns **nil** object.

In your following statement both are strings, hence the error.

```
link[:href] =~ 'http://www.google.com'
```

It should be something like this

```
link[:href] =~ /http:\/\/www.google.com/
```

Comment: Watch out. The above regex won't work. You need to escape both slashes `\/\/` instead of `//`